# Homogeneous Heat Equation Inequality

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Let $I = (0,L)$.

i) There exists $C>0$, such that for all $g\in C((0,L))$ with $\int_{0}^{L}g=0$, the solution u of the Heat Equation

\begin{eqnarray}
u_t=u_{xx} \; \;\;\;\;\;in\; I \times (0,\infty)\\
u = g \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; on\; I \times \{t=0\}\\
u_x(0,t)=u_x(L,t)=0 \;\;\;\;\; t>0
\end{eqnarray}
satisfies the following inequality 
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{0}^{L}u(x,t)^2dx\leq e^{-Ct} \int_{0}^{L}g(x)^2dx
\end{eqnarray}

ii) Let $Q_T=I \times (0,T]$ for $T>0$. Let $a,b,c\in C^\infty(Q_T)$ with $a(x,t)\geq0$ and $c(x,t)\leq0$ for all $(x,t)\in Q_T$. The function $w \in C^\infty(Q_T)$ satisfies the differential equation 
\begin{eqnarray}
w_t - aw_{xx} - bw_x - cw < 0, \; \;\;\;\; in \;\; Q_T. 
\end{eqnarray}

Show that $w$ doesn't have a local positive Maximum in $Q_T$.

It would be very helpful if anyone could help me with a solution or an idea!

Comment: Any thoughts so far?

Comment: Also, do you mean to have the same periodic boundary conditions on $u$, not just $u_x$?

Comment: I thought about using the fundamental solution of the heat equation. No, just on $u_x$. $u_x(0,t)=u_x(L,t)=0$

Comment: I think I got part i) using the answers here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3081101/heat-equation-inequality?rq=1 .

Comment: You should be careful, your boundary conditions are different and don't necessary allow you to apply what they used. This is why I asked my second question.

Comment: Sure, but I use the boundary conditions on equation (5), which in my case would look like this $\int_{0}^{L}(uu_x)_x=u(L,t)u_x(L,t)-u(0,t)u_x(0,t)$. And this is also equal zero for my boundary conditions.

Comment: I'm talking about going from (6) to (7).

Comment: True, the necessary conditions in order to use the Wirtinger's inequality are not met in my case.

Comment: The updated answer on this post solves it, if you haven’t seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1)$ Let's show a counterexample. Consider the function $g(x):=x-\tfrac{L}{2}$ which is clearly continuous and satisfies $$
\int_0^Lg(x)dx=\dfrac{L^2}{2}-\dfrac{L^2}{2}=0.
$$
Now, consider the time-independent function $u(t,x)=g(x)$. Note that this function solves the heat equation. In fact, $$
u_t(t,x)=\dfrac{d}{dt}g(x)=0, \qquad u_{xx}(t,x)=\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}g(x)=0.
$$
Moreover, it satisfies all the boundary condition:$$
\forall t\in\mathbb{R}, \ \, u_x(0,t)=1, \ u_x(L,t)=1,  \quad \hbox{ and } \quad \forall x\in (0,L), \ \,  u(x,0)=g(x).
$$
Nevertheless, this solution satisfies the following property $$
\int_0^L u(t,x)^2dx=\int_0^Lg(x)^2dx, \qquad \forall t\in\mathbb{R}
$$
Thus, there cannot exists any constant $C>0$ such that $$
\int_0^Lu^2(t,x)dx\leq e^{-Ct}\int_0^Lg(x)^2dx,
$$
because the right-hand side is going to zero as $t\to\infty$.

For your second question, you have to go by contradiction. Assume that you have a function satisfying the differential inequality which reaches a local maximum at some point $(x^\star,t^\star)\in Q_T$. Since $w$ is smooth in $Q_T$, we have $$
w_t(x^\star,t^\star)=w_x(x^\star,t^\star)=0.
$$
Then, what can I say about the sign of $w_{xx}(x^\star,t^\star)$? I let you finish this exercise. Once you deduce the sign of $w_{xx}(x^\star,t^\star)$ you can use this information to get a contradiction with you initial inequality.

**For your edited question:** multiplying the PDE by $u(t,x)$ and integrating in $x\in (0,L)$ we obtain $$
\dfrac{d}{dt}\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^Lu^2(t,x)dx=\int_0^Lu_{xx}(t,x)u(t,x)dx=-\int_0^L u_x^2(t,x)dx \qquad (*)
$$
On the other hand, note that integrating directly in the PDE we have
$$
\dfrac{d}{dt}\int u(t,x)dx=\int u_{xx}(t,x)dx=u_x(t,L)-u_x(t,0)=0,
$$
and hence, integrating in time we obtain $$
\int_0^L u(t,x)dx=\int_0^L u(0,x)dx=\int_0^L g(x)dx=0, \quad \forall t\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
Now, it is easy to finish using the solution you are refering in the comments (I saw you modificate the question after you comment that). Since our solution has zero mean for all times, it satisfies the hypothesis of the Wirtinger Theorem for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus, by Wirtinger's Theorem we have $$
\int_0^L u^2(t,x)dx\leq C\int_0^Lu_x^2(t,x)dx, \quad \forall t\in\mathbb{R},
$$ 
where $C>0$ is a positive constant only depending on $L$ (due to the change of scale when using Wirtinger's Theorem in $(0,L)$ instead of $(0,2\pi)$). Plugging this in $(*)$ we obtain $$
\dfrac{d}{dt}\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^L u^2(t,x)dx= -\int_0^L u_x^2(t,x)dx\leq-C\int_0^L u^2(t,x)dx, \quad \forall t\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
Thus, multiplying both sides of the inequality by $2e^{2Ct}>0$ we obtain $$
\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(e^{2Ct}\int_0^L u^2(t,x)dx\right)\leq 0.
$$
Finally, integrating in time from $0$ to $t$ we conlcude $$
e^{2Ct}\int_0^L u^2(t,x)dx\leq\int_0^Lu^2(0,x)dx \ \implies \ \int_0^L u^2(t,x)dx\leq e^{-2Ct}\int_0^Lg^2(x)dx.
$$ 
So the proof is complete. Please let me know if you modify the question, MSE does not notify people when you modify your questions, even if I already answered.

**Second edit:** Please note that, in order to use Wirtinger's Theorem, it is important to prove that $$
\int_0^L u(t,x)dx=0
$$
**for all times** $t\in\mathbb{R}$ (which is not proved in the post you referred in the comments). Otherwise, $u(t,x)$ only satisfy the hypothesis of the theorem at the initial time, which is not enough to ensure $$
\int_0^L u^2(t,x)dx\leq\int_0^Lu_x^2(t,x)dx.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer:)

Comment: @userlogl You're welcome. Please, if it helped you, could you mark it as an answer? (you have to press the ticket at the left side)

Comment: I tried but I got this "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: I have one question.. what do you do here $\int_0^L u(t,x)dx=\int_0^L u(0,x)dx$?

Comment: That equality is proved in my answer and it comes from integrating in time directly in the PDE. Let me write it again: If you integrate (in space) the PDE you obtain $$\dfrac{d}{dt}\int_0^Lu(t,x)dx=\int_0^Lu_{xx}(t,x)dx=0.$$ Then, for any $t>0$, integrating in time the latter equality in $(0,t)$ you get $$ \int_0^Lu(t,x)dx=\int_0^Lu(0,x)dx=\int_0^Lg(x)dx=0.$$

Comment: Btw, to accept an answer you don't have to press the "up vote" buttom (the triangle), you need to press the "ticket" buttom (which is just below the triangles), I think this does not require any minimum reputation.

Comment: Done..sorry I'm new to this